# Using Select All with button checkboxes

Tags: gui-design, buttons, checkboxes, selection

I like the usability enhancement that button checkboxes provide -- nice big click targets, plus we can add a little sliver of color that's used elsewhere in our application to impart a status indicator.

What's tricky is that we want to provide a Select All option that's turned on by default.

[image: Select All box checked, with several checked status buttons below it]

I was thinking about also giving the buttons some kind of subtle highlight color to indicate that they're selected.

My question is: If the user checks a button in the collection below, should it become the only button that is unchecked, or the only button that is selected? Clicking it should uncheck All Statuses, but should it then uncheck all the other status buttons (Or is this pattern totally ridiculous and I should just stick with checkboxes?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your default (assuming based on your domain knowledge) is that all statuses are the useful norm, unchecking one will make that the only one NOT selected, and you can change the **All Statuses** to the semi-selected state:

[image]

If your users are accustomed to the gmail pattern, here's how it works in sequence by clicking the 'Select All' master checkbox:

[image]

If preserving status order and visibility (knowledge of the full range of status) is important, the 'All selected' approach can work. Test to see if a default all option is immediately understood.